# When I change the text file with ini file, the program not working, way?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a  file `installer.ini` where, between many rows I have one `destination=C:\da\`. I want to get the value after `=` and put in a `textBox1`. I made this thing with a text file `test.txt` but when I changed with `installer.ini` doesn't works.
Here is my code :

```
string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
            var link =( path + "installer.ini").ToString();
textBox1.Text = File.ReadLines(link)
     .First(x => x.StartsWith("destination=\""))
      .Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

When I run the program next error appear :

```
Sequence containts no matching element
```

Anyone can say me which is the problem ?

Comment: Your example doesn't have a `"` but your starts with does, that's one problem

Comment: Why are you escaping the double quote? Why not `x.StartsWith("desination="`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the double quote from your LINQ query.

```
string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
            var link =( path + "installer.ini").ToString();
textBox1.Text = File.ReadLines(link)
     .First(x => x.StartsWith("destination="))
      .Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```